# Android Camera: How to process byte data in onPictureTaken using openCV

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to process an image that comes from a `JpegImageCallback` like this

```
    mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mContentView.getCamera().setPreviewCallback(null);
            mContentView.getCamera().takePicture(null, null, new JpegImageCallback());
        }
    });
```

The `JpegImageCallback` looks like this

```
    class JpegImageCallback implements Camera.PictureCallback {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken: I am here! data.length=" + data.length);

        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        int fw = params.getPictureSize().width;
        int fh = params.getPictureSize().height;

        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken: PictureFormat: " + params.getPictureFormat()); /* ImageFormat.NV21 */
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken: PreviewFormat: " + params.getPreviewFormat()); /* ImageFormat.NV21 */

        /* conversion data to Mat */
        Mat mYuvFrameData = new Mat(fh + (fh/2), fw, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        mYuvFrameData.put(0, 0, data);
        Mat rgbImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, rgbImage, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
        Mat gryImage = mYuvFrameData.submat(0, fh, 0, fw);
    }
}
```

The conversion from data to `org.opencv.core.Mat` is copied from `org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView`. It works totally fine when the data comes in `onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera camera)` in a `Camera.PreviewCallback`. But in a `Camera.PictureCallback`like above I get the image wrong.

After the image is taken I display it in a ResultActivity, see below: left is from preview and correct, right is from picture and wrong (green).

[image: Image comes correct in onPreviewFrame] [image: image comes wrong in onPictureTaken]

I already changed the image format to be the same in preview and picture (`ImageFormat.NV21`), but that didn't make a difference. The image format for the picture is `ImageFormat.JPEG` if I don't change it.

So the question is: How do I convert data to Mat to get a correct Image in `onPictureTaken` like in `onPreviewFrame`?

Thanks for any ideas!

Edit:
I dont't want to save the image to disk and I don't want to convert it to a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
        Mat mat = new Mat(new Size(fw, fh), CvType.CV_8U);
        mat.put(0, 0, data);

        Mat rgbImage = Imgcodecs.imdecode(mat, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
        Mat gryImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbImage, gryImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

Found it here: [How to retrieve a new picture taken by the camera as OpenCV Mat on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129906/how-to-retrieve-a-new-picture-taken-by-the-camera-as-opencv-mat-on-android)

`Imgcodecs.imdecode` does all the magic!

There is no need to change the image format, by the way.